# Is this a valid Go path config?

Tags: linux, go, path, debian, gopath

I've placed my path variables as follows:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/Professional/Sch/Fabric/go
export GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

I've placed these lines in both ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc and sourced them both (not sure which of them is taking effect).

my go env output:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/deepak/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/deepak/Professional/Sch/Fabric/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build653871525=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I've placed the following code in $HOME/Professional/Sch/Fabric/go/hellp.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, World!\n")
}
```

but each time i do `go install hellp.go`, I get:

```
go install command-line-arguments: open /usr/local/go/bin/hellp: permission denied
```

which is strange because `go version` returns a `go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64`, and I'm not sure why its trying to reference `/usr/local/go/bin/hellp` as there is no 'hellp' file there, its a sample file I created at `$HOME/Professional/Sch/Fabric/go/`.

I'm not sure which directory permission is missing, but I've tried:

```
  201  sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Professional/Sch/Fabric
  202  go install hellp.go 
  203  sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Professional/Sch/Fabric/go/hellp.go 
  204  go install hellp.go 
  205  sudo chmod -R 777 ~
```

My uname -a output:

```
Linux instance-1 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to install HyperLedger Fabric for which Go is a prerequisite, and clearly `go version` output shows its successfully installed, however, I'm not sure where or how it needs to be configured to test and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your [`GOBIN` setting is telling `go install`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables) to try to install compiled binaries into a system-global directory you don't have permission to write to.  Try unsetting that variable; things should default to being installed in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Also remember that [`go install` takes a package name](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies), not a filename, as its parameter.  I'm not clear you can `go install` something in `$GOPATH/src` directly, but you can move it into a subdirectory

```sh
unset $GOBIN    
cd $GOPATH/src
mkdir github.com/myname/helpp
mv helpp.go github.com/myname/helpp
go install github.com/myname/helpp
$GOPATH/bin/helpp  # uses the name of the package directory
```